# Custom Gantt Chart view is not getting listed in standard view menu list

Tags: csom, sharepoint-online

In my project I am using SharePoint Online and Provider hosted app for provisioning new sites. I was able to successfully provision a new task list in the newly provisioned site and a custom Gannt chart view associated with it.

But the newly created Gantt chart view is not getting listed in the standard view menu list. I can see the view if I access the list of views from the ribbon. Is this is a SharePoint related bug?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

You need modify XsltListViewWebPart tool bar option from one value to another, and then back. That solves that bug in SharePoint.

```
public static void FixGanttIssue(SPList list, string ViewName)
    {
        SPSite site = list.ParentWeb.Site;
        SPLimitedWebPartManager AllItemsMan = site.RootWeb.GetFile(list.Views[ViewName].Url).GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        XsltListViewWebPart wp = (XsltListViewWebPart)AllItemsMan.WebParts[0];
        wp.Toolbar = "Summary Toolbar";
        AllItemsMan.SaveChanges(wp);
        wp.Toolbar = "Full Toolbar";
        AllItemsMan.SaveChanges(wp);
    }
```